# Doctrine2 findBy() on ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have two entities: Project and Course that are linked in a ManyToMany relationship.

Extract from Entity\Project.php

```
/**
 * @var Course[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Talentec\SdBundle\Entity\Course", inversedBy="projects")
 */
private $courses;
```

Extract from Entity\Course.php

```
/**
 * @var Project[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Talentec\SdBundle\Entity\Project", mappedBy="courses")
 */
private $projects;
```

In my controller, I would like to use the Doctrine's findBy() (or findByProject()) in order to find all the courses linked to a certain project.

Is it possible to execute the following:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SdBundle:Course')->findBy(array('project' => $projectID));
```

or:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SdBundle:Course')->findByProject(project_id);
```

I do not think that this is possible, due to the fact that the fields on Course is declared as `$projects` (due to the ManyToMany relationship), and not `$project`.

Is there a similar way to look up entities linked in a ManyToMany relationship?

Answer (score 1):

just use a repository function.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories

EDIT:  Updated link

Comment: Dead link, so this answer is outdated now.

Comment: @DerickF dead again

Comment: @JulesR fixed it again.

Answer (score 1):

In your CourseRespoitory at the directory : src/Respository/CoursRepository.php, 
you can add simple function to return all the courses linked to a certain project like that :

```html
# src/Repository/CoursRepository
// .....
use App\Entity\Project;
// .....

public function findAllCoursByProject(Project $project)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->join('c.project', 'p')
        ->where('p = :project')
        ->setParameter('project', $project)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

and after just call this function in your controller like this:

```html
// ....
Use App\Entity\Course;

//.....

// in your controller 

$em = $this->getDoctrine->getManager()

$courses = $em->getRepository(Course::class)
            ->findAllCoursByProject($project);
```

NB: so don't forget to verify the repository of Course entity , normally it's like this:

```html
# src/Entity/Course.php

/**
 *@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CourseRepository")
 */
class Course
```

Comment: A little mistake in the first snippet I believe: it should be `->join('c.projects', 'p')` instead of `->join('c.project', 'p')`

Comment: Tbh I find this really frustrating, and to me, indicates that the Repository class at a deep level isn't fully implemented properly. There's no reason $repository->findBy() only works for *some* types of properties: the repository class should be smart enough to figure out $courseRepository->findAllByProject($project) without having to resort to essentially writing your own sql with createQueryBuilder